# Tagging words in Vbulletin post with the support of Unicode chars

Tags: php, unicode, preg-replace, vbulletin

I have a Vbulletin plugin which replaces all hashtag with hrefs but it needs to be customized, because it doesn't support non English characters.

For example: #vbulletin will become **#vbulletin**, but #može will become **#mo** že, with only #mo converted as a hash tag.

Since I'm not too skilled in PHP, I will copy the content of the file, in order to better understand.

```
<?php
$hashes = array();
do
{
    if (!$matches = USERTAG::match(preg_replace('#\[(\w+?)(?>[^\]]*?)\](.*)(\[/\1\])#siU', '', $message), 'hash'))
    {
        break;
    }

foreach ($matches as $hash)
{
    $hash = trim($hash);

    if (!$hash)
    {
        continue;
    }

    $hashes[] = htmlspecialchars_uni($hash);
}

if (!empty($hashes))
{
    $hashes = array_unique($hashes);

    if ($info['postid'])
    {
        $hashlist = USERTAG::$db->fetchAll('
            SELECT *
            FROM $usertag_hash AS hash
            WHERE hash :queryList
                AND postid = ?
                AND type = ?
        ', array(
            ':queryList' => USERTAG::$db->queryList($hashes),
            $info['postid'],
            $info['type']
        ));
        foreach ($hashlist as $results_r)
        {
            $key = array_search($results_r['hash'], $hashes);
            if ($key === false)
            {
                continue;
            }

            unset($hashes[$key]);
        }
    }

    foreach ($hashes as $key => $hash)
    {
        $hash = unhtmlspecialchars($hash);

        if (!$hash)
        {
            unset($hashes[$key]);
            continue;
        }           

        $possible = array('/\[hash]' . preg_quote($hash, '/') . '\[\/hash\]/iU', '/#' . preg_quote($hash) . '/iU');
        $message = preg_replace($possible, '[URL=' . $this->registry->options['bburl'] . '/usertag.php?do=list&action=hash&hash=' . urlencode($hash) . ']#' . $hash . '[/URL] ', $message, -1, $found);
    }

    $info['hash'] = $hashes;                        
    }
}
while (false);
?>
```

In my opinion, this is the line which needs to be changed:

```
        if (!$matches = USERTAG::match(preg_replace('#\[(\w+?)(?>[^\]]*?)\](.*)(\[/\1\])#siU', '', $message), 'hash'))
```

As I said, I'm not very well in PHP, so maybe I'm wrong. I tried to change some parts, using examples which I've found here or at other sites, but without any success.

I would really appreciate any help, so I can tag words with Serbian Latin characters like šđžčćŠĐŽČĆ and if possible, entire Serbian Cyrillic characters.

Encoding on my forum is UTF-8, database collation is utf8_general_ci, Serbian letters are properly displayed in posts. I don't know is it matter, but just in case.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from this line that defines two patterns to deal with user tags:

```
$possible = array('/\[hash]' . preg_quote($hash, '/') . '\[\/hash\]/iU', '/#' . preg_quote($hash) . '/iU');
```

You can remove the stupid modifier U *(totally useless most of the time)* that makes greedy quantifiers non-greedy and vice versa, and add the u modifier that gives the ability to deal with unicode characters. So, 
it can be rewritten like this:

```
$possible = array('~\[hash]' . preg_quote($hash, '~') . '\[/hash]~iu', '/#' . preg_quote($hash) . '/iu');
```

The pattern: `#\[(\w+?)(?>[^\]]*?)\](.*)(\[/\1\])#siU` can be rewritten too like this:

```
#\[(\w+)[^]]*](.*?)(\[/\1])#siu
```

Not sure that this will solve all the problem but it's at least a begining.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem, but thank you anyway.